# Получить значение из stdClass Object находящегося в массиве?

Tags: php

```
stdClass Object
(
    [message] => ok
    [result] => 0
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [row] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [ID] => 44926100
                            [MAC] => 12310515551D
                            [Initiator] => visitor
                        )
                )
            [total] => 114
        )
)
```

Помогите пожалуйста получить значение для ID. Пробовал  `$result2['data']['row']['0']->ID`, но явно что не так делаю.

Значение message могу вывести, а вот глубже никак

Comment: А как ты  message выводишь? Покажи

Comment: Для вывода message. $result2->message

Comment: у вас там только `[0]` корректно, остальное - объекты. доступ к полям через `->`

Comment: Если для вывода использовал `$result2->message` (т.е. стрелку),  то почему ты думаешь что остальное надо выводить через квадратные скобки?

Comment: Пробовал через $result2->data->row->ID; , но это не работает

Comment: А куда 0 потерял? Только `row`, как написали выше - массив, а не объект...надо это учесть

Answer (score 0):

Решение которое сработало.
Получить ассоциативный массив: $result2 = json_decode($result, true);
Где $result это входные данные. На выходе получился массив:

```
Array
(
    [message] => ok
    [result] => 0
    [data] => Array
        (
            [row] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 44926100
                            [MAC] => 12310515551D
                            [Initiator] => visitor
                        )

                )

            [total] => 55
        )
)
```

Затем `$result2[data][row][0][ID];`